# Should I use a nested class or an IoC container?

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

I have two classes, Server and Client.  Server needs to instantiate Client in multiple threads and Client has a virtual member that needs to provide a custom implementation.  My question is.  Should the Client class be a nested class of the Server class or should I use an Interface and Dependency Injection to get the custom implementation into the Server class.  Now the Client class also has many private methods that provide some standard logic that shouldn't be changed.

```
public class Server
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++)
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.Process(i);
        }
    }
}

public class Client
{
    private void doSomething() 
    { 
       ...
    }

    // Needs to be overridden and provide custom logic
    public virtual string Process(int i)
    {
        return i.ToString();
    }
}
```

Working example:

```
public interface IClient
{
    string Process(string message);
}

public abstract class Client : IClient
{
    public virtual string Process(string message)
    {
        return message;
    }
}

public class CustomClient : Client
{
    public CustomClient() { }

    public override string Process(string message)
    {
        return string.Format("Custom Client:{0}", message);
    }
}

public class Server
{
    private Func<IClient> createClient;    

    public Server() { }

    public Server(Func<IClient> client)
    {
        createClient = client;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            IClient = client = createClient();
            client.Process(string.Format("Client #{0}", i));
        }
    }
}
```

Test Program...you would step through to see it hit the CustomClient

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<CustomClient> factory = () => new CustomClient();
        var server = new Server(factory);
        server.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the Server needs to create a Client, I'd pass a factory method to the Server for it to use. So I'd go for dependency injection.

Comment: You can pass the dependency in (SRP), but it doesnt have to be an interface to start.

Comment: So lets say I use DI.  How would that work if the Client class needs to be more or less an abstract class?  I would have an interface of lets say IClient and then an abstract class that inherits from IClient that has it's default implementation.  As I stated it has lots of private methods that won't change with only one virtual method that should.  Can I use DI on a subclass of an abstract class that inherits from an Interface?

Comment: > Can I use DI on a subclass of an abstract class that inherits from an Interface? Yes: You just need to pass in a delegate (or factory class instance) that can create an instance of a client class when called from the Server class. The return type could be the abstract type or the interface, but the concrete implementation of the creator will use a specific concrete type, of course.

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking.

Comment: So I think you should pass to the `Server` constructor a `Func<IClient>` and assign it to a private field called, say, `createClient` and then instead of `Client client = new Client();` do `IClient client = createClient();`

Comment: @Matthew Watson It worked like a charm.  Would like to give you credit.  I will post my working example for those interested.

Comment: @ewahner: Glad it worked for you. I've added my comments as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Server needs to create a Client, I'd pass a factory method to the Server for it to use. So I'd go for dependency injection.

For example:  You could pass to the `Server` constructor a `Func<IClient>` and assign it to a private field called, say, `createClient` and then instead of

```
Client client = new Client();
```

use

```
IClient client = createClient();
```

That way you can completely decouple the server and the client.

I prefer using a simple `Func` delegate rather than a full factory class, since that is (a) easier to use and (b) more loosely coupled.

Comment: Is there a reason to pass a factory method or a factory rather than just an instance?

Comment: The abstract class Client must be inherited and instantiated via a delegate factory as the Server class is a concrete class.  I cannot create an instance of it as the Client class can be implemented in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

The question whether a dependency should be injected or fixed has a simple answer - a class providing logic which is a subject of change is a candidate to be injected. On the other hand, if you don't plan to change the logic, you code against fixed types, as you do with most base class libraries.

What you describe sounds like a scenario for DI - if you allow to override the client class then you assume that changes are possible. DI is one of most obvious ways to handle the dependency and the change in the same time.